# Mailto links not working on one specific page in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, email, hyperlink

The mailto links on the following page do not work in Chrome 32.0.1700.107:
http://accelerate.numa.paris/Accelerate-Apply

I have checked Chrome's settings and the associated handler is Gmail, other page with mailto links seem to work correctly as they generate a new email in Gmail, for example:
[W3Schools mailto example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto)

A problem with Chrome settings is therefore to be excluded.
I have read that the problem might be linked to Google Analytics, unfortunately I do not have access to that as the page has been created within a CMS.

Any help regarding the nature of the problem and possible solutions that do not involve using javascript are welcome.

Comment: I'm using outlook 2010 and the link works perfectly fine in the same version of chrome.

Comment: I'm using Apple Mail on OS X Mavericks and i can also verify that they work here on version 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: Thanks for testing, it seems I am so far the only one having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to only affect users logged in with an account of the NUMA website, therefore this will not affect the average visitor.

The reason why this is happening would be difficult to answer for anyone that doesn't have an account and is probably less critical at this point.